# How to create trigger in Visual Studio 2017 to insert log details into a table?

Tags: visual-studio, triggers, visual-studio-2017

I am getting error with the following code while taking the timestamp to create a log for every insertion.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[log_trig]
ON [dbo].[CUSTOMER]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NoCount ON
    DECLARE @_id INT
    DECLARE @_time TIMESTAMP
    SET @_id = NEW.id
    SET @_time = now()
    insert into log values (@_id, @_time)
END
```

Comment: What does the error says?

Comment: It says Unexpected Connection.